# conceal the deadlock problem from the end-user is desirable

Tags: database-design

Why is it desirable to conceal deadlock from the end user? What if end user would see the deadlock?

Comment: Probably bad error handling practice to not conceal it. Rather you should implement a graceful error handler / message for the end user or implement automatic retry logic appropriate to the context of the application.

Comment: Many thanks @J.D.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deadlock is the result of some serious application logic error and should never happen with an application designed and written to work in a way such that deadlocks can never occur (eg by always obtaining locks in the same order). Caveat here is that no one is running simultaneous manual transactions on the database in which case all bets are off.

To show a deadlock error message to an end user is silly; they have no idea what to do with it. It's better to log the error and display a message to the user that is more meaningful to them, or possibly to try again automatically.

Comment: Many thanks @Colin 't Hart!